# Select rows in postgres where JSONB field in provided list

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

Say I have table in Postgres with column `data` of type `JSONB`. This column contains pretty complex object for example:

```
{
  ...,
  gender: ['men', 'women'],
  ...
}
```

I have query like `gender=men&gender=women&gender=something_else` and want to find all rows in table where ANY of `gender's` members `IN ('men', 'women', 'something_else'). For example:

```
SELECT uuid, data ->> 'gender' FROM "OX_Articles" WHERE data ->> 'gender' INTERSECTS WITH (men', 'women', 'something_else');
```

Of course we haven't keywords `INTERSECTS WITH`.

Comment: Correct, we don't have that syntax.  You should read the docs to see what we **do** have.  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either [`in (...)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparisons.html#FUNCTIONS-COMPARISONS-IN-SCALAR) or [`= any(array[...])`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparisons.html#id-1.5.8.28.16) should work.

They should have similar performances. I favor `=any` because it handles empty RHS (whereas `IN` can't handle empty literal tuples) and I'd expect whatever postgres bindings I have to convert the host language's arrays/lists/arraylists to pg arrays, not pg tuples.